# jython reading file from jar file

Tags: java, python, jython

I have jar/zip file contains properties file called accord.properties under classes folder.

```
Zip/Jar file:
  +classes
      +accord.properties
```

I am reading file as:

```
from java.util import Properties
from java.io import File, FileInputStream
def loadPropsFil(propsFil):
    print(propsFil)    
    inStream = FileInputStream(propsFil)
    propFil = Properties()
    propFil.load(inStream) 
    return propFil
pFile = loadPropsFil("/accord.properties")
print(pFile)
```

while running in Tomcat server, I am getting error as

```
Exception stack is: 1. accord.properties (No such file or directory) (java.io.FileNotFoundException) java.io.FileInputStream:-2 (null) 
2. null(org.python.core.PyException) org.python.core.Py:512 (null) 
3. java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: accord.properties (No such file or directory) in <script> at line number 34 (javax.script.ScriptException)
```

Tried with

```
pFile = loadPropsFil("accord.properties")
```

and

```
pFile = loadPropsFil("classpath:accord.properties")
```

same error.

**EDIT**

```
inStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("accord.properties")
strProp = Properties().load(inStream) # line 38
options.outputfile=strProp.getProperty("OUTPUT_DIR")
```

Here inStream gives null and causes NullPointer Exception.

**Error:**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException in <script> at line number 38 (javax.script.ScriptException)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access files in a JAR like a normal file using `FileInputStream`. Instead, you need to access them as *resources* using [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). Try something like this:

```
inStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("accord.properties")
```

---

I'm glad you were able to figure out how to call getResourceStream. I'm not sure what the "Mark invalid" error means. This works fine for me:

```
    $ CLASSPATH=hello.jar:$CLASSPATH jython
    Jython 2.5.3 (2.5:c56500f08d34+, Aug 13 2012, 14:48:36)
    [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from java.lang import ClassLoader
    >>> from java.io import InputStreamReader, BufferedReader
    >>> inStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hello.txt")
    >>> reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inStream))
    >>> reader.readLine()
    u'Hello!'
```

Since `hello.jar` contains the file `hello.txt` which has the single line `Hello!`, the above is my expected output.

Comment: @akb - I don't get an error running your code. `pFile.getProperty("OUTPUT_DIR")` returns `u'/home/mulesoft/report/'` on my machine if I use the properties file you posted. You don't still have a `/` before `accord.properties` do you?

Comment: @akb - Try removing one line at a time to figure out which is causing the problem. You might try switching to an XML properties file instead and see if that fixes the problem. Also, you could try generating the properties file using the `store` or `storeToXML` methods on the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

Comment: Now I am getting inStream is null, but my property file is exists under the jar classes folder.